# About adding to lists

Tags: list, concatenation

```
def do_something(a, b):
    a.insert(0, 'z')
    b = ['z'] + b
    a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    a1 = a
    a2 = a[:]
    b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    b1 = b
    b2 = b[:]

do_something(a, b)
```

Why does `a` give `['z' 'a' 'b' 'c']` while `b` gives `['a' 'b' 'c']`?
I thought because they're same types they should merge.

Answer (score 1):

`b = ['z'] + b` creates a new list and makes the local variable `b` point to it. The original list is not modified.

In contrast, the `insert` method changes the existing list, so its effects can be seen outside of your function.